# Why'd a claimant be allowed to recover deposit if it acts in bad faith, when a contract obligated good faith and reasonable endeavour?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

[*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract* (Core Texts Series)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p. 83

> 4.29 A similar issue arose in a slightly diﬀerent way in *Shaker v Vistajet Group Holding SA*
>   (2012). There, the claimant paid a deposit in respect of the purchase of an aircraft from
>   the defendant under the terms of a letter agreed by the two parties. The letter expressly
>   provided that the claimant agreed to proceed in good faith and to use reasonable endeavours to agree the formal sale contract and associated documents. The formal contract
>   could not be agreed, so the claimant sought repayment of the deposit, but the defendant
>   refused, contending that the claimant had not complied with its **[1.]** good faith and **[2.]** reasonable endeavour obligations. Teare J accepted that the intention of the agreement was that
>   the deposit could only be recovered if these obligations had been complied with, but
>   held that the obligations were unenforceable because of the impossibility of ‘polic[ing]’ them, that is, of working out whether they had been breached or not. It distinguished

p. 84

> the *Petromec* decision on the basis that there were objective criteria available in that
>   case to assist the court in determining whether the obligation had been breached. It is
>   respectfully suggested that Teare J may have been too ready to find that the obligations
>   were unenforceable, as **this [unenforceability of reasonable endeavour obligations]** would have allowed the claimant to recover its deposit even if
>   it had acted in bad faith** (which on the facts it did not). There are many types of conduct
>   that everyone would agree constitute bad faith, so if the conduct fell into this category,
>   there would be no practical impediment to the court policing the obligation.

As the contract had the two obligations that I numbered on p. 43, I don't understand the emboldened sentence.

If the claimant acted in bad faith, then wouldn't it breach [1.]? If it did, then why would the unenforceability of reasonable endeavour obligations "have allowed the claimant to recover its deposit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the claimant acted in bad faith, then wouldn't it breach [1.]? If
>   it did, then why would the unenforceability of reasonable endeavour
>   obligations "have allowed the claimant to recover its deposit"?

Yes. Bad faith would constitute breach, but the court in [*Shaker v. Vistajet Group Holding SA (2012)*](https://www.casemine.com/judgement/uk/5a8ff73360d03e7f57ea9906) (paragraph 7) explains that in some contexts

> there are no objective criteria by which the court can decide whether
>   a party has acted unreasonably.

In the *Shaker* case, unenforceability is twofold. One aspect is the ultimate non-sequitur of "*keep negotiating and re-negotiating in good faith*". First, because "*an agreement to negotiate or agree further agreements is unenforceable in law*". And second, because "*the parties may legitimately have differing views or interests*" (Shaker, paragraph 12), thereby making it very hard for a court to ascertain "good faith".

The other aspect of unenforceability pertains to the loan/funds (or written confirmation from a financier) that Shaker would have to obtain in order to complete the purchase. That duty is unenforceable insofar as Shaker cannot coerce the financier (paragraph 17).